# how to clone/copy html table using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem here, that when I click the copy button on the recently copied row. It doesnt work. You guys know how to fix this?

This is my code

```
var controller = function(num1) {
    $('#copy-' + num1).click(function() {

      var $tableBody = $('#table_name').find("tbody"),
        $trLast = $tableBody.find("#tr-" + num1),
        $trNew = $trLast.clone();
      // $trNew.find('input').val('');
      $trLast.after($trNew);
      console.clear()
      // refresh_index();

    });
  }

  function refresh_index() {
    $('#table_name > tbody > tr').each(function(i) {

      i++;
      var select = $(this).find('select');
      var text = $(this).find('input');
      var button = $(this).find('button');

      controller(i);

    });
  }
  refresh_index();
```

This is my code in [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/solomon099/9zL5nve7/12/)

Answer (score 2):

To attach the click event on dynamically created element use the delegation approach using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). This will allow the event to work on the elements those are added in the body at a later time.

Change

```
$('#copy-' + num1).click(function() {
```

To

```
$('body').on('click','#copy-'+num1, function() {
```

```js
$(function(){

 var controller = function(num1){
    $('body').on('click','#copy-'+num1, function() {

      var $tableBody = $('#table_name').find("tbody"),
          $trLast = $tableBody.find("#tr-"+num1),
          $trNew = $trLast.clone();
          // $trNew.find('input').val('');
          $trLast.after($trNew);
          console.clear()
          // refresh_index();

    });
  }
  
  function refresh_index(){
   $('#table_name > tbody > tr').each(function (i) {

      i++;
      var select = $(this).find('select');
      var text = $(this).find('input');
      var button = $(this).find('button');

      controller(i);

    });
  }
  refresh_index();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_name">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>No</th>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="trs" id="tr-1">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Mouse</td>
      <td><button class="copy" id="copy-1">Copy</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trs" id="tr-2">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Keyboard</td>
      <td><button class="copy" id="copy-2">Copy</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trs" id="tr-3">
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Monitor</td>
      <td><button class="copy" id="copy-3">Copy</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding it after the dom is loaded so it will not find it. If you use the on function to target something that was in the dom before it was dynamically added then add the target in the second variable after "click" then it should work.

```js
$(function(){

 var controller = function(num1){
  
    var newThingy = '#copy-' +  num1;
    
    $("#table_name").on("click", newThingy, function() {

      var $tableBody = $('#table_name').find("tbody"),
          $trLast = $tableBody.find("#tr-"+num1),
          $trNew = $trLast.clone();
          // $trNew.find('input').val('');
          $trLast.after($trNew);
          console.clear()
          // refresh_index();

    });
  }
  
  function refresh_index(){
   $('#table_name > tbody > tr').each(function (i) {

      i++;
      var select = $(this).find('select');
      var text = $(this).find('input');
      var button = $(this).find('button');

      controller(i);

    });
  }
  refresh_index();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_name">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>No</th>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="trs" id="tr-1">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Mouse</td>
      <td><button class="copy" id="copy-1">Copy</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trs" id="tr-2">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Keyboard</td>
      <td><button class="copy" id="copy-2">Copy</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trs" id="tr-3">
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Monitor</td>
      <td><button class="copy" id="copy-3">Copy</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use delegate event like `$tableBody.find('.copy').off('click').on('click',function(){});` and bind click event after cloning the `tr` better to use `class` instead of `ids`. Here is the updated code based on your jsfiddle.

```js
var $tableBody = $('#table_name').find("tbody");
clickEvent();
function clickEvent(){
  $tableBody.find('.copy').off('click').on('click',function() {
          $trLast = $(this).closest('tr'),
          $trNew = $trLast.clone();
          $trLast.after($trNew); 
          clickEvent();
  });
   function refresh_index(){
   $('#table_name > tbody > tr').each(function (i) {
      i++;
      var select = $(this).find('td').eq(0).text(i);
    });
  }
  refresh_index();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_name">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>No</th>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="trs" id="tr-1">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Mouse</td>
      <td><button class="copy" id="copy-1">Copy</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trs" id="tr-2">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Keyboard</td>
      <td><button class="copy" id="copy-2">Copy</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trs" id="tr-3">
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Monitor</td>
      <td><button class="copy" id="copy-3">Copy</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```